# Replace windows wallpaper with animation?

Tags: windows, animation, user-interface, desktop

I was curious if it is possible to write some app that'll replace windows wallpaper with some very simple animation (like slide in strings)?
I've seen some very beautiful concept of destop, and I'd like to try implement it, cause I don't know if there will be something like that released.

Comment: There is no supported way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no such existing animation.

But anyhow, that's a great idea.

Comment: Thanks! I know there's something called Active Destop, but I'm not quite familiar with it.